# Excel dynamic calendar: bank holidays per country

Tags: excel, calendar

Morning all,

Having a few issues with a project at the moment.

I have 2 sheets, one listing a table of bank holidays in a dozen countries (Country eg. UK, Holiday eg. New Years day, Date eg. 01/01/2017) the second sheet is a 12 month calendar. selectedCell is a blank cell to the right of the holiday table and a little piece of VB pulls the date which is currently selected on the calendar. Ive then got an index formula to list the holidays on that selected day which then displays to the right of the calendar.

There is also some conditional formatting on the calendar highlighting the day if there is a holiday for anyone listed in the table.
point. Id like to have the country in a drop down above the calendar so that it 
It could do with some refining and im not sure what else I can try at this just shows the bank holidays for the specified country and not all of them. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much in advance! [image] [image]

Comment: you can create the dropdown listbox and write a conditional if bassed on the value of the linked cell to get the holiday for the country

Comment: Its the condition that I am struggling on. Its not my strongest area of excel and I am struggling to work out what it would need to be..

Comment: post the condition you have used for getting dates

Comment: I used the below but it highlights all holiday dates for all countries and im unsure about how to adjust it so that I can specify country to highlight the bank holidays for. Not even sure how I got to this!:
=MATCH(B7,Holidays!$C:$C,0)>0

Comment: use =match(b7&b8,Holidays!$C:$C&Holidays!$A:$A,0)>0  here b8 should be linked to the value of the list box.....and commit the formula using ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: You've lost me, sorry :( B7 would be "Su" and B8 "01/01/2017" in the calendar. Cant commit with ctrl+shift+enter in the conditional formatting area either?

Comment: for conditional formatting add another rule you can have more than one rule

Comment: B7  cell has your date value....for the list box link a cell to get the value....it does not have to be b8 it can be anything

Comment: or just upload your file and share the link i ll check the file and give you a solution

Comment: Uploaded to: https://ufile.io/c506e1

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub getdates()
Dim dts As Range
Dim cntry As Range
Dim ctry As String
Dim dt As Variant
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Sheets("Holidays").Range("G8:I100").ClearContents

dt = Sheets("Holidays").Range("I4")
ctry = Sheets("Holidays").Range("I5")
lrow = Sheets("Holidays").Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
Set dts = Sheets("Holidays").Range("C2:C" & lrow)
Set cntry = Sheets("Holidays").Range("A2:A" & lrow)
i = 8
For Each cell1 In cntry
If cell1.Value = ctry Then
For Each cell2 In dts
If (cell2.Value = dt) And (cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value = ctry) Then
Sheets("Holidays").Range("G" & i).Value = cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value
Sheets("Holidays").Range("H" & i).Value = cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value
Sheets("Holidays").Range("i" & i).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value
i = i + 1
End If
Next cell2
End If
Next cell1
Sheets("Holidays").Range("G8:I100").RemoveDuplicates &_
Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

add this sub routine to your code and call this within the selection change event within the if condition you have added.

then add a combobox  create a list value range and refer it in the combo box get the value from a linked cell, get the country name by offseting using thelist box value to the cell i5 and this will work

Comment: i have also uploaded the file here https://ufile.io/f45f0    check the link

Comment: if you find the answer useful or if its what you are looking for....please make sure that you make it the bext answer andupvote it

Comment: Unbelievably I still have no idea what i'm doing even with the downloaded file. Thanks for all your help today anyway